# vuex store getters not working in a component

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

Can anyone see why this wouldn't work please,

Trying to use vuex store to manage my axios requests and transfer to a component as follows:

In my vuex store module I have the following

```
import axios from "axios";
export const state = () => ({
    cases: [],
  })

  export const mutations = {

    listCases (state, cases) {
      state.cases = cases;
    },     
  }

  export const actions = {

    loadCases ({ commit, context }) {

      return axios.get('http')
      .then(res => {
        const convertCases = []
        for (const key in res.data) {
          convertCases.push({ ...res.data[key], id: key })
        }
        commit('listCases', convertCases)
      })
      .catch(e => context.error(e));
    },

  export const getters = {
  // return the state
    cases(state) {
      return state.cases
    }
  }
```

I checked amd my axios request is returning my results as expected and passing to the mutation

In my component I have

```
import { mapMutations, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {

  created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('cases/loadCases');
  },

  computed: {
      ...mapGetters ({
      cases: 'cases/cases'
    })
},

</script>
```

Now i assumed based on what I've learnt that i could call with 
 and this would return my items.

but i get an error cases is not defined,

Anyone abe to tell me my error please

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection

You may be able to make it reactive this way:

```
export const mutations = {
  listCases (state, cases) {
    state.cases = [];
    cases.forEach((c) => {
      state.cases.push(c);
    });
  },     
}
```